# Flight Layout ThimPress (Wordpress) template at Safari

Tags: css, wordpress

I ask about the help of experts wp, I myself could not find in which direction to dig.

**Problem:** (only) at safari browser when scrolling page drop css (restructured DOM).

Screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/a371nKioyH1Uyw

**How to repeat:**

1. open page and scroll down;
2. scroll to top;
3. over content appears foter and/or sidebar.

**Example page:**

http://142.93.111.137/education/?p=353

http://int20.ru/?p=467

- site work on wordpress.
- teamplate (ThimPress education pack): https://thimpress.com/product/education-pack-1-free-education-wordpress-theme/
- Can check on domains:

http://int20.ru

http://142.93.111.137

Comment: On SO we are using english. Please edit your question.

Comment: ... but can you also post your original question on https://ru.stackoverflow.com I think

Comment: Sorry, thx. I redid.

Comment: Your best bet for support for a premium WP theme is to contact the themes author.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to remove the bootstrap.